# How do I configure apache to recursively check parent directories for missing files?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Given the following requests:

1. myhost.com/path/to/foo.js
2. myhost.com/path/to/some/other/foo.js

and on my server I have files at:

1. /foo.js
2. /path/to/some/foo.js

How do I configure apache to fallback to resource 1 for request 1 and resource 2 for request 2.

I'm hoping for a configuration that walks up directory tree checking for requested files when the don't exist at originally requested location.

Comment: only for foo.js or any request?

Comment: Any request. So `foo.js` and `bar.js` would hopefully both 'fallback' using this same rule.

Answer (score 0):

This should do, placed in VirtualHost `.conf` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([^/]+)/([^/]+$) $1/$3 [N]
```